# DataTables multiple column sorting with or without orderFixed columns doesn't work

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, multiple-columns

I need to pre-sort by one column (selection) and post-sort by one column (name in ABC order). Basically what I want is that the selected items should be always on the first half of the table. Then a user may pick one column to sort by (for example GPA), and then there would be always a post sort by name. It doesn't work as I expected. If I click on the GPA it seems to ignore the fixedOrder pre column of checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/WYzn5/7/

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Selected</th>
            <th>Candidate</th>
            ...
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "orderMulti": true,
    "orderFixed": {
        "pre": [ 0, 'asc' ],
        "post": [ 1, 'asc' ]
    },
    "paging": false,
    "scrollX": "300px",
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "searching": false
});
```

In general, if I don't use fixedOrder columns and I try to sort programatically by multiple columns, it also doesn't work. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: A simpler fiddle works fine, so maybe knockout causes some problem? Couldn't figure out though, just guessing.

Comment: The problem is with the checkbox column. DataTables couldn't interpret it, I guess because it has the knockout binding somehow?. If I add a `<div data-bind="text: selected().toString()"></div> `ahead of the checkbox input, the sorting starts to work well immediately (until you change the checkbox state, that's another story again, sigh...). I tried to suggest the order type and stuff for DataTables like with `columnDefs`, `orderDataType`, no luck yet.

Comment: So right now I add hidden text in front of the checkbox control, but I'm planning to transition to DataTables natively and get rid of knockout bindings for the table itself.